# Mini DisplayPort to DVI-D Dual Link up to 2560 * 1600

Tags: dvi, cable, thinkpad, adapter, mini-displayport

I have a ThinkPad T530 with Mini DP++ and NVS 5400M, which are said to support 2560 * 1600 resolution. The display is Dell 3007WFP, which also supports 2560 * 1600. But, I have never seen any cables or adapters that can connect them with full support to 2560 * 1600.

Do you have any idea? THANK YOU!

In addition, I found that mDP++ means I can use a passive adapter. No need for active adapter which is much more expensive.

[This](http://www.clicktronic.com/en/products/dvi/productview/mini_displayportdvi_adapterkabel_casual/) is the only one that meets my needs, but it is not sold in the US. And [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0043GWDAM) one seems to be OK, but I am not sure because it says "2.5 Gbps per channel", which may not be enough.

Comment: Thanks for this question! It was the only one regarding the T530 and NVS 5400M and getting greater-than-full-HD resolution. Ordered the adapter suggested by @IlanBiala and the 27" IPS-ZERO-G Slim Monitor WQHD 2560x1440. Will report back with results for future visitors of this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The cable at you show that is sold in the USA is fine because it specifically lists that it supports 2560 x 1600 resolution. However, The alternative is a cable from [monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=6904&seq=1&format=2), which also supports 2560 x 1600 resolution, it is a little more expensive, and there isn't much difference from the two, but the real problem is what connector your monitor is. [Take a look at this picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/DVI_Connector_Types.svg/181px-DVI_Connector_Types.svg.png), if your monitor's dvi connector is the second one, then you have to find a connector with that connection standard instead of the more usual 4th connector. Then you know if you can get either of the adapters above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using DVI-D dual link, that is the 4th one. But the MONOPRICE one you provided is (I think) an active adapter because it has an USB, which is usually seen on active adapters to provide extra power. But I prefer a passive one because it is cheaper.

Comment: Agreed, though I'm not sure a passive is the best choice when going for the highest resolution, though that is up to you. You can find the difference at the DVI wikipedia page, hope you find everything you need there. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface